# EasyUI comboxbox doesn't load options in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, jquery-easyui

I have a custom module that hooks the Easyui Javasript framework to Drupal 7, the problem is if I try to expand the easyUI combox that is already loaded with data I get an error:

In chrome: `jquery.easyui.min.js?nisjtz:11827 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'zIndex' of undefined`

In Mozilla: `TypeError: $.fn.menu.defaults is undefined jquery.easyui.min.js:11827`

It also behave the same for EasyUI datebox (datepicker) But the same code works fine when not hooked to drupal, Any Ideas why this is happening?